# flutter_blue Connect Macos bluetooth device.discoverServices error

Tags: dart

macos version 11.6 flutter_blue version 0.8.0

The device service has been failed to get, but I can get the service normally when I get it on my mobile phone. However, the service is not available on the Mac OS

Error occurred at

```
var services = device.discoverServices();


2021-11-16 11:32:03.486 flutter_xxxx[43362:321219] uuid: xxxxxx-23e0-4bdc-ac16-xxxxxxxx value: (null)

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: The format is invalid
#0      Guid._fromString (package:flutter_blue/src/guid.dart:45:7)
#1      new Guid (package:flutter_blue/src/guid.dart:15:39)
#2      new BluetoothCharacteristic.fromProto (package:flutter_blue/src/bluetooth_characteristic.dart:35:27)
#3      new BluetoothService.fromProto.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_blue/src/bluetooth_service.dart:19:29)
#4      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:413:31)
#5      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:342:26)
#6      new _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:188:27)
#7      new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:150:28)
#8      new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:50:28)
#9      ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:213:44)
#10     new BluetoothService.fromProto (package:flutter_blue/src/bluetooth_service.dart:20:14)
#11     BluetoothDevice.discoverServices.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_blue/src/bluetooth_device.dart:67:38)
#12     MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:413:31)
#13     ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:342:26)
#14     new _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:188:27)
#15     new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:150:28)
#16     new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:50:28)
#17     ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:213:44)
#18     BluetoothDevice.discoverServices.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_blue/src/bluetooth_device.dart:67:69)
#19     _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:213:31)
#20     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
#21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436:47)
#22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
#23     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
#24     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
#25     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
#26     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
#27     _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:218:10)
#28     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
#29     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436:47)
#30     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
#31     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
#32     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
#33     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
#34     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
#35     _WhereStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:195:12)
#36     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
#37     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436:47)
#38     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
#39     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
#40     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
#41     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
#42     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
#43     _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:218:10)
#44     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
#45     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436:47)
#46     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
#47     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
#48     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
#49     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
#50     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
#51     _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:218:10)
#52     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
#53     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436:47)
#54     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
#55     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
#56     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
#57     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
#58     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
#59     _WhereStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:195:12)
#60     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
#61     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436:47)
#62     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
#63     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
#64     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
#65     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:14)
#66     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:706:11)
#67     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:663:7)
#68     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1420:47)
#69     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
#70     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
#71     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
#72     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1428:13)
#73     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
#74     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
#75     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
#76     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
#77     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
```

Error occurred at
guid.dart

```
 static List<int> _fromString(String input) {
    if (input == null) {
      throw new ArgumentError("Input was null");
    }

    input = _removeNonHexCharacters(input);
    final bytes = hex.decode(input);

    if (bytes.length != 16) {
      throw new FormatException("The format is invalid");
    }

    return bytes;
  }
```

string input is "" error . can you help me analyze why